# Proving a quite general irreducible affine variety is birationally equivalent to $\mathbb{A}^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Here's the question:

> $X\subset \mathbb{A}^{n+1}$ is the zero set of a polynomial $P$ which is irreducible and has the form $P=P_d+P_{d+1}$, where $P_d, P_{d+1}$ are nonzero homogeneous of degree $d, d+1$ respectively. Prove that $X$ is birationally equivalent to $\mathbb{A}^n$.

First I tried examples with low $n,d$ to maybe find a pattern which would help me construct the general birational map. But for low $n$ and/or $d$ the problem is so simple it does not give any insight for the general case.

Then I tried using preparation lemma to reduce a $n,d$ case to lower cases and maybe do some induction like construction. I couldn't do much because I really can't figure the restriction conditions on $P_d, P_{d+1}$, such that $P$ is irreducible. This irreducibility seems to be the key.

Another thing I tried was using the fact that if there are two dense open subsets $U\subset X$ and $V\subset \mathbb{A}^n$ and $U\simeq V$ then $X$ and $\mathbb{A}^n$ are birationally equivalent. Again since I can't see the properties necessary for $P_d, P_{d+1}$ couldn't get so far.

Any hints? Specially if somebody can tell me the significance of this special form of polynomial.

Comment: Try homogenizing $P$.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I show that $\mathbb{A}^n$ is birationally equivalent to the projective hyperplane given by homogenization of $P$?

Comment: Yes. Then you'll see what the significance of the degree condition is, which you haven't really used.